# Solution to Hyperbolic PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, closed-form

Let $A\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ be Lebesgue integrable, and $c_1,c_2\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ also be Lebesuge integrable.  Consider the hyperbolic PDE
$$
\begin{cases}
\partial_{x,y}u & = A\cdot u\\
u(x,\cdot) & = c_1\\
u(\cdot,y) &= c_2
\end{cases}
$$

Is there a known closed-form expression for the solution to this type of PDE?

**Disclaimer:**  *This is a question which came up during some research, but since I don't to PDEs and this question seemed basic I did not ask on MO. *